# SharePoint document library sync issue (multiple users - changes are reset)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, onedrive

Got a SharePoint Online site with a single document library. This library is synced to approx. 5 users local drives (clicked on sync button - contents are synced by OneDrive.exe to local machine).

From time to time renaming a folder or other changes are reset a few minutes later. SharePoint Online seems to have problems seeing what version is newer when multiple users machines are syncing files from one location and sometimes keeps the old version instead of the change.

The document/folder does not get a new version. It remains on the old version before the change.

**- How can I uncover which client/user causes the issue?**

**- How can I prevent SharePoint Online from doing this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem when some use working with document inside folder 'Documentation' and somebody wants to rename this folder... It'S correct that he is not enable to rename it, cause the user which working with the document should have problems with saving this document and sync it to Online environment.

If you want to rename files and folders, **I recommend to do this only in SharePoint Online environment, cause this is the main data source.** But user which editing some documents may have problems with saving them.